# How to disable ktlint rule for Missing newline after ":" and Missing newline after ","

Tags: android, kotlin, ktlint

Having trouble where to find a specific solution to disable **Missing newline after ":"** and **Missing newline after ","** of ktlint rules, when running **ktlintCheck** in my kotlin codes in Android

This is my code that encounters error:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(),
   DateSelectionListener, AttachmentsSelectionListener,
   LocationStateListener
{

}
```

This is what the ktlint requires me to format my code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), DateSelectionListener, AttachmentsSelectionListener, LocationStateListener
{

}
```

I just wanted to bring the interfaces below one another since bunch of interfaces consumes too much of code line.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `ktlint-disable` [comments](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#how-do-i-suppress-an-errors-for-a-lineblockfile), like:

```
// you can use a block comment
/* ktlint-disable parameter-list-wrapping */
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(),
   DateSelectionListener, AttachmentsSelectionListener,
   LocationStateListener
{

}
/* ktlint-enable parameter-list-wrapping */

// or eol comment
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(),
   DateSelectionListener, AttachmentsSelectionListener, // ktlint-disable parameter-list-wrapping
   LocationStateListener
{

}
```

Looks like [v0.46.x of ktlint](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#disabling-for-a-statement-using-suppress) also supports suppressing checks via `@Suppress`, but the gradle plugin hasn't caught up yet, though it looks like a pr is in draft.